# Is there a way to natively validate the customer form fields with Square?

Tags: validation, square, custom-error-handling

I am using PHP Connect to submit a simple payment via Square.  I’ve added a customer object, but do not see any validation settings for fields with the customer object via Square’s API.  There must be a way to set custom required fields when dealing with a customer object.  Can someone please point me the right way?

Here is the PHP script I am using to connect to Square:

https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/connect-examples/v2/php_payment/index.php

As you can see, there is an onclick event in the button submit:

```
      <button id="sq-creditcard" class="sq-button" onclick="requestCardNonce(event)">
```

I can remove this event and validate fields via jQuery, but I am having trouble when attempting to run the event on successful validation.  Here is one example I have tried:

```
$(“form”).submit(function(){

    $(“input”).each(function(){
        if($(this).val()){
            good = true;    
        }else{
            good = false;
        }

    });

    if(good){
        requestCardNonce(event);
    }
});
```

This is just a stripped down version of what I am attempting.  Essentially, just passing the requestCardNonce(event) after everything checks out.  But when I do this, it breaks...

Comment: Are you just trying to ensure a customer fills out certain fields (like first name)? If so, shouldn't that be handled on your client-side Javascript (or even PHP backend), rather than Square? If that's not what you mean, can you provide a bit more context please?

Comment: @sjosey yes.  I've attempted client-side Javascript, but that seems to break the built-in onclick function of the PHP library.  I'm updating the question with more context now.  Thx.

Comment: @sjosey I've just updated it.